# What is the precise mathematical definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = −∞$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the precise mathematical definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = −∞$? As x approaches infinity.

I know what the general meaning is, but I heard my teacher talk about some precise mathematical definition.

Comment: as any of a million online resources will reveal to you: for all $M\in \mathbb R$, there exists $N\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)<M$ for all $x>N$. Note that there are plenty of equivalent variants though.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = - \infty$ if for $M > 0$, there exists $K > 0$ such that if $x > K$, then $f(x) < -M$.

*Source*: "Introduction to Mathematical Analysis" by Parzynski and Zipse; Page 86, Definition 3.8 (c).